# Would 反駁 be the Mandarin equivalent to 駁嘴?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

駁嘴 in Cantonese means to "answer back" or "argue" often in a disrespectful way. URL: http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/16019/

Would 反駁 be the Mandarin equivalent to 駁嘴?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

駁嘴 means '**to talk back**' (reply defiantly or insolently),  usually against someone has authority over you (like parent, teacher, boss)

Example of 駁嘴:

> *Father: "Son, you must have a good education to get a good job"*
>
> *Son: "Oh, yeah? How about Bill Gates? He didn't finish college"*

反驳 means  '**to rebut**' or '**to refute**' . You are trying to prove that someone's statement is wrong or to expose the falsity stated by someone

Example of 反驳:

> *A: "Give the corporations a huge tax cut will create a lot of jobs"*
>
> *B: " No, it will not! The corporations will just buy back their stock to make more money for themselves. You can check the history, it happened many times"*
>
> *A: " To stop bad guys with guns you have to have good guys with guns"*
>
> *B: " No, having more guns in people's hands doesn't solve the gun violence problem. Almost no Japanese have guns and gun related death in Japan last year was three"*

*駁嘴 in Cantonese is same as 顶嘴 in Mandarin

Answer (score 1):

駁嘴 means "argue" and "quarrel", while 反驳 means "raise points to debate" and is emotionally neutral.

What you may want is 拌嘴，which means "quarrel".

Comment: 拌嘴 (quarrel) is mostly between two parties that are roughly at equal standing. For example: husband and wife; 駁嘴 (talk back) is mostly from one party that's below the other in rank or status